# Unable to get the time stamp in file name by using batch script in Windows Server 2022

Tags: batch-file

I am unable to get the time stamp in file name by using batch script in Windows Server 2022 Datacenter 64-bit Version 21H2(Build 20348.1487). Could you please help me on this.

### Batch Script

```
SET dataauditfilename=myAuditReport
rem Section to rename the file

Set Timestamp=%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%
ren "%dataauditfilename%.CSV" "%dataauditfilename%_%Timestamp%.CSV"
```

The above batch script works in Windows 11 but not in Windows server 2022 Datacenter 64-bit Version 21H2(Build 20348.1487).

Comment: Please use the `search` facility in the top bar and search for `[batch]date`. This question is asked repeatedly. The root cause is that date/time format is user-dependent, so without an indication of what format **you** are using, it's a guess. I'm particularly suspicious of your `time` substringing. My time format is `20:26:59.64` for instance, so that would yield `06:` using your code (2`0`:2`6:`59.64), which is nonsensical and includes a character that's illegal in a filename.

Comment: May be be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236) will be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format)

Answer (score 0):

Could you write how you would want the file name be? Ie: 01_30_2023_2310 (This is my current date and time (01/30/2023 - 23:10).

When i run at the cmd the name your script should set Timestamp (`%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%`), i get **01_30_2023_312%** and maybe that's why isn't working.

Anyway, if my suggestion of name is what you want, then the script should be:

```
SET dataauditfilename=myAuditReport
rem Section to rename the file

Set Timestamp=%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
ren "%dataauditfilename%.CSV" "%dataauditfilename%_%Timestamp%.CSV"
```

Comment: Tried your script in Win Server 2022 but not getting timestamp with file.